# Querying Morphia by Id

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia, the Pojo mapper for MongoDB, and I find difficult a task that in my view should be very simple: getting an object by id. I am able to find all the objects in a collection but I cannot figure out the simple task of querying using an id I got from the list. I am actually talking about the ObjectId. If I try to render it in JSON I see

Answer (score 13):

This question seems incomplete.

It also seems like the answer to you question is on the [Morphia QuickStart page](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/QuickStart). Seems to be as simple as follows.

```
Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore("testDB");
String hotelId = ...; // the ID of the hotel we want to load
// and then map it to our Hotel object
Hotel hotel = ds.get(Hotel.class, hotelId);
```

So you'll definitely need more details.

Comment: never forget to add "@Id ObjectId id" to entity. It turns you life easier.

Comment: I suppose that he want's the query for the same reason I do. For example, updateFirst wants a query if we want to use the createIfMissing. So we can build a query or just use the key we have to build a query. But if you don't want to specify the name of the id, just the value. You want an operation that gives you a query using only id value...

Comment: Unfortunately this technique is deprecated in newer versions of Morphia.  It will still work at least until they remove the get method from DataStore. The recommended approach is to use the Query class to get things by id.
// Given ObjectId id;
Query<Hotel> query = datastore.createQuery(Hotel.class);
query.criteria("_id").equal(id);
return query.first();

Comment: Thanks @SteveOwens, I just realized that this post was written 9 years. Not long after this post, I actually started working with Scott Hernandez, the original creator of Morphia. But it's actually gone through two other major contributors since then. Neither of us work an Mongo any more. https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/graphs/contributors

So I'm not really sure what to do here. Do you have official docs for "the new way"? Should we just tag this question with a morphia version number?

Comment: Well from my perspective it really doesn't matter.  I have switched to spring-data-mongo and have been much happier with the api.

Answer (score 8):

```
Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore("testDB");
String hotelId = "516d41150364a6a6697136c0"; // the ID of the hotel we want to load
ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(hotelId);
// and then map it to our Hotel object
Hotel hotel = ds.get(Hotel.class, objectId);
```

Comment: Can you explain why your code works or what it's doing? The best answers explain the solution, rather than just functioning code.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht In the previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4475711/1094584) is incorrect. MongoDB Id is not the type String. Type of MongoDB Id is ObjectId (org.bson.types.ObjectId).

Answer (score 7):

If you're finding by id and the id is provided by the user (means that it could be whatever type of data), you shouldn't use the solutions given above.

As explained in the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.4/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#ObjectId%28%29), an ObjectId *consists of 12 bytes*, so if you pass something else to `new ObjectId(myValue)`, your code will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Here is how I implemented the method to find by id :

```
public Model findById(String id) throws NotFoundException {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(id);
    Model m = datastore().find(Model.class).field("_id").equal(oid).get();
    if (m == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated in Morphia 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

The previous explanation used the deprecated methods: `datastore().find(Model.class).field("_id").equal(oid).get();` My variant of it on  Morphia 2.2.10:

```
public Optional<Hotel> findById(final String id) {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }

    final Query<Hotel> query = datastore.find(Hotel.class)
        .filter(eq("_id", new ObjectId(id)));
    return Optional.ofNullable(query.first());
}
```